# Учу питон по байт питона, немогу понять как работает 3 строка и item в цикле фор

Tags: python-3.x

```
shoplist = ['яблоки', 'манго', 'морковь', 'бананы']
print('Я должен сделать ', len(shoplist), 'покупок.')
print('Покупки:', end=' ')
for item in shoplist:
    print(item, end=' ')
print('\nТакже нужно купить риса.')
shoplist.append('рис')
print('Теперь мой список покупок таков:', shoplist)
print('Отсортирую-ка я свой список')
shoplist.sort()
print('Отсортированный список покупок выглядит так:', shoplist)
print('Первое, что мне нужно купить, это', shoplist[0])
olditem = shoplist[0]
del shoplist[0]
print('Я купил', olditem)
print('Теперь мой список покупок:', shoplist)
```

Comment: `end=' '` указанное как параметр `print` означает, что при выводе вместо переноса на новую строку будет добавляться пробел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
print('Покупки:', end=' ')
```

По умолчанию функция python print () заканчивается новой строкой (\n - next line, где \n (Управляющая последовательность)).

```
print('Покупки:', end=%anything%)
```

способ вывести что-то отличное он \n в соответствии с Вашими пожеланиями

В

```
print('Покупки:', end=' ')
```

вместо перехода на новую строку будет ставиться пробел, следующий вызов функции print() продолжит вывод в последнюю строку, а не на новую

2.

```
for item in shoplist:
```

range-based loop (перебор последовательности в которой можно определить начало и конец) и перебрать все элементы этой последовательности (отдельная итерация цикла на каждый элемент), где
item - элемент который берется из коллекции при каждой итерации цикла for
shoplist - сама коллекция

пример

```
for item in shoplist:
    print(item)
```

выведет в консоль все элементы коллекции (каждый с новой строки)